# How to apply filter using xlwings python

Tags: python-3.x

I have used the below line to set a filter on b column using xlwings. It is not showing any error while running this code line but not able to see filters in the sheet.

```
wb.sheets[0].range('B3:B5').autofilter = True
```

Kindly suggest me a solution to this.